# how to compare entry from the previous

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table of consumptions

```
  create_table "consumptions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float "kilometers"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
  end
```

Here is a list of consumptions for user 1

```
 #<Consumption:0x007f8654895080     
  id: 1,
  kilometers: 10000.0,
  created_at: Wed, 07 Nov 2018 15:23:21 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 07 Nov 2018 15:23:21 UTC +00:00,
  user_id: 1>,
 #<Consumption:0x007f865489c268
  id: 4,
  kilometers: 10800.0,
  created_at: Wed, 24 Oct 2018 14:30:23 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 08 Nov 2018 12:35:37 UTC +00:00,
  user_id: 1>,
 #<Consumption:0x007f8654893f50
  id: 6,
  kilometers: 11400.0,
  created_at: Thu, 08 Nov 2018 11:56:52 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 08 Nov 2018 12:36:42 UTC +00:00,
  user_id: 1>,
```

I want to compare the **difference** of kilometers between each consumption...

```
consumptions

id |   km  | 
1  | 10000 | 
4  | 10800 | 
6  | 11400 |
```

Result between id 1 and 4 should be 800

Result between 4 and 6 should be 600

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to take a look at https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails
You just need to add `acts_as_mappable` to your model (decide if you config your default values or place them in your model, I think the best would be to do it on a config file).

Then you just use  `by_distance` method and your code would look so much nice :)

Comment: I don't think it's going to work, I am not measuring distance between locations.
I am measuring gas consumptions
First fill in my car has 10 000km  (0)
Next fill in my car has 10 700km  (700 km were done since the previous fill in)
Next fill in my car has 11 300km (600 km were done since the previous fill in))

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using?

Basically, you want to use a window function:

E.g. for PostgreSQL:

```
select id, kilometers - lag(kilometers) over (order by id) as difference? from consumptions;
```

[PostgreSQL reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)

[MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html)

[Another example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691462/postgresql-calculate-difference-between-rows)

You could then use [find_by_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506432/postgres-window-function-column-with-rails) to retrieve the value as an ActiveRecord model, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506432/postgres-window-function-column-with-rails).

> The results will be returned as an array with columns requested
>   encapsulated as attributes of the model you call this method from.

I haven't tried it but yours would look like:

```
Consumptions.find_by_sql('select id, kilometers - lag(kilometers) over (order by id) as difference? from consumptions')
```

Comment: sorry, what is missing from this answer that you want to see?

Comment: How do I turn your answer into a rails method?

Comment: Thanks for you help 
Maybe I wasn't clear enough, I want to find the difference between each consumption for a given user. (Consumption belongs to user)

Answer (score 0):

To give more of a 'ruby' answer:

```
def difference_in_km(obj_1, obj_2)
  (obj1.kilometers - obj2.kilometers).abs
end
```

The abs is there to handle negative figures, returning 400 instead of -400 for example.

This lets you do:

```
con_1 = Consumption.find(1)
con_2 = Consumption.find(4)

difference_in_km(con_1, con_2)
```

Another approach would be to add an instance method to your Consumption class:

```
class Consumption < ApplicationRecord
  ....
  ....

  def distance_from(other_consumption)
    (kilometers - other_consumption.kilometers).abs
  end
end
```

This will allow you to do:

```
con_1.distance_from(con_2)
```

Comment: That's the way I tried.
As I iterate over **@consumptions**  how to find in each round the previous user's consumption kilometers?

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way:

So I added an attribute `difference` set by default to `0` to `consumptions`

```
class Consumption < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

    before_save :count_difference

    def count_difference
        if Consumption.any?
            if Consumption.last.user_id == self.user_id
                self.difference = Consumption.last.kilometers - self.kilometers
            end
        end
    end

end
```