# How do I set an attribute of an object based on its relation to other objects' attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, attributes

I have a simple golf app, and for each player I have `:total_score` and `:current_place` attributes.  I want Rails to define the `:current_place` attribute of each player based on whether that player's `:total_score` is higher or lower than the other players.

In other words, if there are two players, and one has a `:total_score => 5`and the other has `:total_score => 4` I'd like Rails to make the first player's `:current_place => 1`, and the other player's `:current_place => 2`, and so on.  I basically want it to define the `:current_place` values based on the descending of the `:total_score` column.

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813495/howto-rank-items-by-balance-in-ruby-on-rails or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103767/getting-a-rank-from-activerecord

Comment: Also might want to try gem [rankitize](https://github.com/supapuerco/rankitize)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that with an observer that when a player is saved launches and sql query and then updates the attribute(using update_attribute so it doesn't trigger callbacks). But that would be a not very performant solution and could have race condition problems too.

Another solution would be to have this same query materialized in some place and make the current_place function of the model access the results. This could be easily cacheable too

Code:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  def current_place
    self.class.current_place(self.id) if self.id
  end

  def self.all_places
    rank = {}
    pos = 0
    self.order_by('total_score desc').each{|p| rank[p.id] = (pos += 1)}
    rank
  end

  def self.current_place(id)
    all_places[id]
  end
end
```

I didn't test it but I guess that something like this should work. To achive the cached part you only need to wrap all_places in a Rails.cache.fetch block and expire it every time a player total score is updated