# Greater than in ActiveRecord query fails with floats?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to calculate ranking for values in my Rails app.

I was following example in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103767/getting-a-rank-from-activerecord)

```
def rank
  User.where("points > ?", points).count + 1
end
```

Initially I verfied it with integers and it was working. But I also have need to rank floats.

For example, I have following values

```
0.6238564767774734
0.03700210614260772
0.022441047654982744
0.00935025180031852
0.0016195952859973067
0.0010382902478650936
0.0009367068270665785
0.0004916500182958447
0.00016560735047205894
```

If I call query

```
User.where("points > ?", 0.6238564767774734).count + 1
```

It returns 2. Why is that, shouldn't it return 0 as there are no values that are bigger than it? Also, queries with fourth and fifth values both return value of 5.

SQL queries from console as follows:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (points > 0.623856)
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (points > 0.00935025)
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (points > 0.0016196)
```

Just in case I also tried length and size instead of count.

What is wrong and how I could I fix it? All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem with difference between that how mysql rounds floats and how ruby rounds floats. Using decimal instead of float might be a better idea.

Also take a look at
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html

Comment: Thank you. Was able to correct my calculation based on this. Changed my column to decimal and introduced some bigdecimal as well.

Answer (score 1):

`0.6238564767774734` goes beyond the precision of a float.

What you'd get in Postgres (I'm unaware of a `pg_typeof()` equivalent in MySQL):

```
denis=# select pg_typeof(0.6238564767774734);
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 numeric
(1 row)

denis=# select 0.6238564767774734::decimal, 0.6238564767774734::float;
      numeric       |      float8       
--------------------+-------------------
 0.6238564767774734 | 0.623856476777473
(1 row)
```

On its end, Ruby is using a `BigDecimal`. The MySQL type that would match it (more or less in MySQL, since you need to specify the precision) would be the `decimal` type:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html

Be wary that MySQL requires a precision in this case:

```
mysql> select cast(0.6238564767774734 as decimal);
+-------------------------------------+
| cast(0.6238564767774734 as decimal) |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                   1 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select cast(0.6238564767774734 as decimal(20,20));
+--------------------------------------------+
| cast(0.6238564767774734 as decimal(20,20)) |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                     0.62385647677747340000 |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Lastly, note that you'll still get errors due to rounding problems related to how floating point types are represented, if you stick to floats and adjust your criteria:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding

(I'm guessing you're using decimals internally in there somewhere, but the above set of problems related to floats are good to have in mind when doing comparisons.)