# How to Return index position of hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

All, I am attempting to calculate the winning percentage of each user in a group, sort the users by winning percentage, and return the user's rank -- that is, the position where the user's winning percentage is set within the group.

So, the function should return "1" for the user with the highest winning percentage.

So far my code is:

```
def rank (user, group)
    users = UserGroup.select(:user_id).where(group_id => group)
    user = user.id
    rank = Hash.new
    users.each do |user|
      total = Game.where("group_id = ? AND (user1 = ? OR user2 = ?"), group user_id, user_id).count
      win = Game.where(:group_id => group, :winner => user).count
      win_percentage = win/total.to_f
      ranks[:user] = win_percentage
    end
    ranks.sort_by{|key, value|, value}.to_h
    return ranks.each_with_index.detect{|(key, value), index| key == user).last +1
end
```

I think everything should be fine, but I can't figure out how to return the index of a the hash based on the key. I think that I might need to convert into an array of arrays and use Array#index; but I am also unclear on how to find an index of an array of arrays.

Comment: Not sure whether parts of your code are even valid Ruby code.  Is the above code pseudo-code or real code?

Comment: I used short for the active record queries -- that is, the users, total, and win assignments.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103767/getting-a-rank-from-activerecord and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813495/howto-rank-items-by-balance-in-ruby-on-rails ?

Comment: Interesting, though I don't think those help because I am not storing winning % in active record, but calculating it in the function.

Comment: I'm more or less a beginner, so I'd love some reasoning behind the down votes if possible.  The down vote itself doesn't really help me improve.

Comment: I did not downvote - but I guess  your question is very unclear - you have tried to not share the code that you are working with and what you  have shared is not proper ruby code - it is confusing.  Also, you have not shared details of either your DB table or class definition of ActiveRecord model due to which people will be left to guess what fields they have to work with

Comment: Got ya -- I wasn't not sharing to hide anything obviously, but I thought the pseudo code would make it easier to focus on the actual issue.  Thanks for the advice going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to return the index of a the hash based on the key

You can use `each_with_index`. A quick example:

```
hash = {:h=>1, :k=>2, :v=>3}
hash.each_with_index.detect { |(key,value),index| key == :k }
# => [[:k, 2], 1]
hash.each_with_index.detect { |(key,value),index| key == :k }.last
# => 1
```